# passing data from one collectionView cell to other collection view controller in swift 4 by sending "ID" as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a query regarding Collection View in Swift 4.

I have a collection view name it as `Category-Collection-View-Controller`. 
In this, each Category has a unique ID which is coming from the back-end. When I click on the specific category it will navigate to the other collection view which is named as `SubCategories-CollectionView-Controller`. and display all the information of the "Category-Collection-View-Controller". Please, anyone, explain to me how I pass the "ID" which is coming from the backend as a parameter in Alamofire function.

Comment: Your other collection view is in other view controller?

Comment: yes. I have two collection views. 1 is "Category Collection View" . 2 is "Sub Categories Collection view". when i click on the row of the "Category Collection View " it will navigate to second view controller that is "Sub Categories Collection view". and display all sub categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from one view controller to another with the following ways:

- Delegates
- Segue
- Notification

I will suggest you use segue since you must have performed segue action on category tap.

Coding Example:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   // You can use a traditional push view controller method.
   //let id = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item]
   //let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubCategories-CollectionView-Controller"") as! SubCategories-CollectionView-Controller
   //vc.id = id
   // self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

        // Get the category id and pass it through segue 
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: id)
    }
```

and in `prepare for segue` method, you can just pass this id to next view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let senderID = sender as? Int
        let vc = segue.destination as? SubCategories-CollectionView-Controller
        vc.id = senderID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let id = dataArray[indexPath.item]
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubCategories-CollectionView-Controller") as! SubCategories-CollectionView-Controller
        vc.id = id
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

Here dataArray is your array of data through which you are showing data in Category-Collection-View-Controller. Now when you user tap on it you can get the data in the didselectitem method and pass it to next controller.

Answer (score 0):

Declare id in CategoryCollectionViewController and than fetch subcategory details using this id.

```
class CategoryCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    var id : Int?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         Almofire.FetchSubcategory(catid:id) {  catgorydata in
              subcategoryCollectionView.reloadData()
         }
     }
}
```

in your categoryCollectionView Controller pass Category id from CollectionView didselect methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let categoryID = categoryArray[indexPath.row]
        let subcategorycontroller = SubCategoryController()
        subcategorycontroller.id = categoryID
        self.present(subcategorycontroller, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```